# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAbsoluteScale' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

I am trying to transform circle but it throws error. I don't understand what is the problem i have already worked with transformations on `Konva.Rect` and there's no such error. Attaching **transformer** to `Konva.Circle` works properly, but when mouse is over one of **transformer** anchors it throws error. Here's how i'm attaching transformer to `Konva.Circle`:

```
this.setState({ attachedToId: id }, () => transformer.attachTo(clickedNode));
```

My `Konva.Circle` component to which i'm trying to attach **transformer**:

```
<Circle
      id={id}
      ref={this.circleRef}
      x={x * linesWidth}
      y={y * linesHeight}
      radius={radius * linesHeight}
      stroke={color}
      onMouseUp={this.mouseUp}
    />
```

**Transformer** attaching is happening when `this.mouseUp` is called

Comment: Can you make a small online demo?

Comment: @lavrton here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/0qolmy452n)

Answer (score 1):

From your demo `attachObject(node) { }` function has a Konva node as the first argument. You should change the way you call it:

```
handleClick = e => {
  const { attachObject } = this.props;

  // e - is event object
  // the next line will not work
  // attachObject(e);

  // instead you should do this:
  attachObject(e.target);
};
```

Make sure you update the layer when you attach `Konva.Transformer`:

```
attachObject = node => {
  const t = this.ref.current;

  t.attachTo(node);
  t.getLayer().batchDraw();
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wxvx5xyk5

Comment: I'm sorry but i've made mistake in my example. I pass node from react reference like this: `attachObject(this.circleRef.current)`. And i have to tell that my problem is disappeared. I actually didn't touch my code for a day, and next day i tried again and it's just gone. Thank you for your answer but it's just some mysterious thing happened :D